# Dynamically adding data from an API to a table with React

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-hermann-so8dg

I attempted mapping through a list array that I created and I can add an `<li>` with what the user typed. But I have all of my info in a table that I would like to add rows after each API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code I have tried to work out your aim. 
So using what you had I updated your table list file and the Nutrition file.

The way I made your table dynamic was instead of passing a food item into your TableList component, it takes a list of food objects that it then maps through to create a row for each one. The foodList is a modified version of your list, this is where an object containing your food information is added

The structure of the food object is:

```
  const foodObject = {
                calories: responseData.nf_calories,
                protein: responseData.nf_protein,
                food: responseData.item_name
              };
```

And adding it to the list is done like so:

```
          setFoodList([...foodList, foodObject]);
```

where the foodObject is added to the previous food list via destructuring.

The updated code sand box is here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-morse-migmn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Hopefully you could look at the changes and find something helpful

Good luck :D

If you need any other help or explanation, feel free to ask, happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I didn't realize the original upload didn't work at first. That's literally exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm just not as familiar with destructuring and certain React concepts yet.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking how does the code look in general? I'm self taught so I'm just trying to make sure I'm using best practices or not writing absolutely horrid code.

Comment: Hey again, 
You were on the right track, just seems that you may have had some confusion of the best way to store the data. You had an individual useState for each property of the food. The better dat structure would be using an object and store each property as a key value pair (The foodObject I created). 
Your overall structure of your application is good!
I would also recommend using something like axios for your api calls. Might help clean up some of the code. But apart from that it looks good :), nice work

Comment: I would also recommend having a few more details/examples in your stackoverflow question XD 
Some people don't like that haha

Comment: Thank you so much again. You're my hero. I tried it again with your data structure & it worked great! You're a lifesaver. I was getting so frustrated with this.

Comment: And that makes me feel so much better. I felt like I was on the right track but learning online, you tend to doubt yourself. & I've used axios before. After trying it this way I definitely feel like that's the better option as well.

Comment: Just wanted to add my original question had a lot of detail but the moderator edited it & brought my question down to a paragraph.

Comment: Happy to help! Best of luck! Also, feel free to mark my answer as the accepted one. I don't actually know how to do that though

Comment: Nice I didn't even know that was a thing . I think I did it